# How to refer a jenkins shared library specific branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I have a repository for a jenkins shared library named "jenkins-shared-library" , now I created a new branch called "test",

I have an application that need to use this jenkins shared library inside a jenkins file, currently it is being referred as

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-library')_
```

I want to use this specific test branch of my jenkins-shared-library inside my jenkinsfile, how can I use the specific branch of jenkins-shared-library???

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at the [Shared Libraries Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), there are several ways to control the version of a shared library across the pipelines.

First option is to define the version in *Global Pipeline Libraries* configuration - which will affect all the pipelines that are using that library.

The second option, which is probably what you need is to use the *version specifier* when loading the library, the format will be `@Library('my-shared-library@<BranchName>')`. The version specifier can be a branch name, a git tag and so.

```
// Using a version specifier, such as branch, tag, etc
@Library('my-shared-library@1.0') _
// Accessing multiple libraries with one statement 
@Library(['my-shared-library', 'otherlib@abc1234']) _
```

**Important** If you want to override the version of a default library defined in the in *Global Pipeline Libraries* you must enable the *Allow default version to be overridden* in the Shared Library’s configuration - or else you wont be able to use a custom version.

When loading libraries dynamically (using the `library` step) you can also specify a version: `library 'my-shared-library@master'`, and since this is a regular step, the version could be computed  at runtime rather than just using a constant value as with the annotation.
for example: `library "my-shared-library@$BRANCH_NAME"`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the 'test' branch simply by declaring it as

`@Library('jenkins-shared-library@test')_`

Answer (score 1):

Also can be done in **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure System**

under: **Global Pipeline Libraries** change the **Default version**

[image]