# Trouble With Referencing Shared Libraries in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We are attempting to reference a shared library in Jenkins in a pipeline using the syntax described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68370923/how-to-refer-a-jenkins-shared-library-specific-branch) with @branch_name syntax. We have the "Allow Default Version to be overwridden" setting set. Yet, the pipeline ignores changes in the branch, and uses the version of the library in master. Any advice on additional settings/configuration needed or suggestions to make this work are appreciated.

We tried this syntax specifically: @Library('library_name@feature_branch_name')

Additionally, I specifically see an entry in the console output: "Loading library library_name@feature_branch_name". Yet, somehow it ignores the changes that have been commit in that branch, instead running against master.